# Firebase and Android - Chat Message and OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I learn Firebase and I found this project: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/0.3.1/codelabs/chat

I'm trying to expand this project for setOnClickListener method.
I would like to click on every item of this chat message(chat listview) and see
this in another activity.

For example: I have this chat in: ChatMessageActivity. And I would like show this in ChatMessageDetailsActivity.

Like this:

[image]
       private Firebase firebaseRef;
       private static final String FIREBASE_URL = "https://my-project.firebaseio.com/chat";
       FirebaseListAdapter listAdapter;

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_message);

        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        firebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);

        final EditText mText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageText);

        Button sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = mText.getText().toString();
                ChatMessage message = new ChatMessage("Android User", text);
                firebaseRef.push().setValue(message);
                mText.setText("");
            }
        });

        final ListView listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.list);
        listAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this, ChatMessage.class,
                android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, firebaseRef) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
                ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(model.getName());
                ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(model.getText());
            }
        };
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        firebaseRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }

            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { }
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { }
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { }
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) { }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if ( row == null || (row.getTag() == null)) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.chatName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.detsName);
            holder.chatText = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.detsText);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        holder.chatName.setText(holder.chatMessage.getName());
        holder.chatText.setText(holder.chatMessage.getText());

        final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
        row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ChatMessage.this, ChatMessageDetails.class);

                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        return row;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        ChatMessage chatMessage;
        TextView chatName;
        TextView chatText;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        listAdapter.cleanup();
    }
}
```

But getView(at the bottom) method doesn't work. I had this in my old project without Firebase and internet connection. It worked. But now I'm trying to implement this in Chat Project but without positive results.

Is in Firebase some inside method to do this?

Does somebody has some preposition how to develop this listView with SetOnClickListener method with Firebase in AndroidStudio?

Comment: You should be using an **Item** Click Listener, not a **View** Click Listener

Comment: And that get view method at the bottom.  Is that in an Activity class, or an Adapter?

Comment: @cricket_007 That is in this ChatMessage class. Should I create my own CustomListAdapter?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking, but it would seem you want an item click listener on the ListView, and that starts a ChatDetail activity. Is that correct? If so, then no, `ChatMessage` is simply a class to hold data. Messages are stored in an Arraylist. That Arraylist is stored in an Adapter. That Adapter is loaded to a ListView. When you add a View.OnClickListener to a ListView, the same event happens for any item because it's detecting a click on the entire ListView, rather than items

Comment: Okey. Thank You. I will correct this!

Comment: You shouldn't use this git repo, it uses deprecated methods (since May 18, 2016). See yourself: https://www.firebase.com/docs. Use instead https://firebase.google.com/docs/. If you want chat example, Google made a repo: https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat (without auth). You can also take a look to my repo https://github.com/omaflak/Firebase-Secure-Chat (with auth)